# Hide already visited results on Google? Maybe using stylesheets?

Tags: css, user-interface, google-search

(Not sure if SO is the right site for this question, please move it if not)

I regularly perform site-specific Google searches (site:stackoverflow.com css) and would like to hide all results that I already have visited (where the link is purple rather than blue). The purpose is to see what's new since my last search (I click on all new links every time I perform this search to make the links appear visited).

Is that possible to do with something like a custom stylesheet? Or any other method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done in CSS alone - you probably don't want to hide *just* the visited `<a>`s, but also their containers, but CSS can't target *upward* like that.

You could use a userscript (with [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)), but visited links aren't detectable via JS, so you'd have to save clicked links in storage. Something like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Hide Visited Google Links
// @include          /^https://www\.google\.\w+/search/
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

if (!localStorage.visited) {
  localStorage.visited = '[]';
}
JSON.parse(localStorage.visited).forEach((visitedHref) => {
  const a = document.querySelector(`a[href="${visitedHref}"]`);
  if (a) {
    a.closest('.g').remove();
  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  const g = target.closest('.g');
  const a = target.closest('a');
  if (!g || !a) {
    // Need to click on a search result container *and* an <a>
    return;
  }
  const visited = JSON.parse(localStorage.visited);
  visited.push(a.href);
  localStorage.visited = JSON.stringify(visited);
}, true);
```

From my machine, the result links are in a `.g` container. I don't know if this is how it is worldwide or not - if not, you'll have to change the two `.g`s in the code to whatever selector matches the container on your end.

Comment: Hmm, does _visited links aren't detectable via JS_ rule out a scriptlet/bookmarklet? After thinking a bit more on this I realised that a scriptlet that I could invoke with a click probably would have been an even easier solution than manually applying a CSS.

Comment: A userscript is similar to a more structured bookmarklet. Visited links aren't detectable via JS, *but* you can detect clicks on tags that probably result in the links being visited, and programmatically save / retrieve those links from storage, as is done in the answer.

Comment: :-( Browsers should add more "levels" to their security model. Manually executed javascripts from the console should have access to everything. There are no other tools than JS or CSS that could be useful in this case?

Comment: Not really, but with front-end stuff, there aren't exactly any tools *other* than JS and CSS (and HTML) that can ultimately be used. But don't be afraid of using userscripts (Javascript) - they're a great way to customize your browsing experience.